# CSS make table into one column with label automatically from thead

Tags: html, css

When making multiple-columns table into one column using CSS, how to make the labels
of the data to be automatically created from thead information?

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) is about to make multi-columns table into one column when screen becomes
narrow. But the "Label the Data" part is hardcoded.

```
/*
Label the data
*/
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
```

Could we automatically get the labels from thead and use them here, not hardcoded?

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Job Title</th>
    <th>Favorite Color</th>
    <th>Wars or Trek?</th>
    <th>Porn Name</th>
    <th>Date of Birth</th>
    <th>Dream Vacation City</th>
    <th>GPA</th>
    <th>Arbitrary Data</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
```

The attached is `responsive_table.html` program.

Comment: this is possible, see here to learn how you can manipulate pseudo-elements using js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after

Answer (score 0):

use HTML5 attribute:

```
#some-id td:before { content: attr(data-title); }


#some-id td:before {
/* Now like a table header */
position: absolute;
/* Top/left values mimic padding */
top: 1px;
left: 6px;
width: 45%;
padding-right: 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align:left;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and then:

```
<tr class="padding">
     <th>
          sth
     </th>
<tr>
<tr>
      <td data-title="sth">

      </td>
</tr>
```